# Linear Programming - at most 3 variables are not zero

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

> We have the following LP problem:
>
> $\max \ c_1 x_1+c_2 x_2+\dotsb+c_n x_n$
>
> $\sum^n_{j=1}a_{ij}x_j\le b_i \ : \ i \in \{1,2,3\}$
>
> $x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n \ge 0$
>
> Assume that there exist a feasible solution,and that the problem is bounded.
>
> Prove that there exists an optimal solution,which has at most 3 variables which are not equal to $0$.

Any ideas???
Or hints?

Comment: The fundamental of theorem of linear programming tells us that if there is an optimal solution (the problem is in wrong, because the LP could be unbounded!) then there is an optimal basic feasible solution.

Comment: @ChikChak -- Perhaps it was also specified that the constants $a_{ij}$ are positive? Or maybe the problem was stated as "_If_ there is an optimal solution, then ...".

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes,the LP is indeed bounded.

Comment: @quasi question was edited.

Comment: @mvw question was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following constructive algorithm builds an optimal solution with at most $3$ variables which are not equal to $0$:

> **For i = 1,2,3 :**
>
> 1. Order the variables by non increasing order of the ratio $c_j/a_{ij}$.
> 2. Let $F_i$ be the index of the variable that comes first in the list.
> 3. **If $F_i$ has not been selected yet:**
>
>    $\quad$ Set $x_{F_i} = b_i/a_{ij}$
>
>    **Else:**
>
>    $\quad$ Let $\alpha$ be the value of  $x_{F_i}$. Set $x_{F_i}=\min\{\alpha, b_i/a_{ij}\}$
>
> Set $x_j=0\; \forall j \notin \{F_1,F_2,F_3 \}.$

For each constraint, you select the variable that has highest cost and lowest contribution to the left hand side of the constraint (step $1$), and you set its value the maximum value possible (step $3$). In the worst case, the selected variable is different for each $i=1,2,3$, so you have $3$ variables that have a positive value.

Comment: I am curious about this: you chose three variables to be non-zero, but it seems that all three constraints are not satisfied by your solutions?